# Nginx redirect only root domain but not subdomain to www

Tags: nginx, proxy, wildcard, reverse-proxy, wildcard-subdomain

Currently I'm using setting below to redirect non-www domain to www domain and it's working fine:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

However, now I would like to allow wildcard subdomain but it seems like all the subdomains were being redirect to www.domain.com. So my question is how can I make it only redirect the root domain to www only and excluding all other subdomain? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first server block is also the implicit *default server*, which means that any domain name that does not match `www.example.com` will be handled by it.

If you would like that second server block to handle all domains except `example.com`, you can make it the *default server* explicitly, by adding the `default_server` option to the `listen` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...
}
```